# Replacing inline string in file using sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I've below lines in one of my startup scripts (abc.sh):

```
runuser root -c "export CATALINA_OPTS=\"-Xms5g -Xmx10g\"; \
    nohup $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh $CATALINA_HOME > /dev/null &"
```

I want to replace -Xms5g -Xmx10g with below line:

```
-Xms500m -Xmx1g -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9000,server=y,suspend=n
```

I wrote a script myscript.sh which contains below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i~ 's/-Xms5g -Xmx10g/-Xms500m \
    -Xmx1g -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9000,server=y,suspend=n' ./abc.sh
```

But its giving me error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 95: unterminated `s' command
```

Can any one help me out in correcting this command?

Note: There are other several lines as well in abc.sh

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to add a `/` at the end.

```
sed -i~ 's/-Xms5g\s*-Xmx10g/-Xms500m -Xmx1g \
    -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9000,server=y,suspend=n/' ./abc.sh
```

Pattern should be like this: `s/regexp/replacement/`